# Which files can I remove from /boot

Tags: boot, upgrade, disk-usage, delete

I need about 60M more free space to upgrade from 18.04 Ubuntu version to 20.04. I see that a few file names are the same but with different number at the end, maybe some of them are older versions which are not being used?

```
ls -lh /boot
total 115M
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    231K Mar 30  2020 config-5.3.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    233K Apr 16 11:44 config-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    233K May 11 10:56 config-5.4.0-74-generic
drwxrwx--- 4 root plugdev  512 Dec 31  1969 efi
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root    1.0K Jun 13 12:00 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     17M Apr  8 16:23 initrd.img-5.3.0-46-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     29M May 21 19:27 initrd.img-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root     30M Jun 13 12:03 initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
drwx------ 2 root root     12K Jan 31  2020 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    179K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    181K Jan 28  2016 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root    4.3M Mar 30  2020 System.map-5.3.0-46-generic
-rw------- 1 root root    4.4M Apr 16 11:44 System.map-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw------- 1 root root    4.4M May 11 10:56 System.map-5.4.0-74-generic
-rw------- 1 root root    8.8M Mar 30  2020 vmlinuz-5.3.0-46-generic
-rw------- 1 root root    9.1M Apr 16 11:44 vmlinuz-5.4.0-73-generic
-rw------- 1 root root    9.1M May 11 10:58 vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic
```

Sorry if this is hard to read, I wrote it with help of translator.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 is a different product to Ubuntu Core 20.  Ubuntu has both *year.month* or *deb* based products, and *snap* only products which use the format *year* only.  As they are different products, you are not intended to upgrade from one to the other, a *year.month* format product such as 18.04 is QA-tested to upgrade to the next release (18.10) or the next LTS (20.04) and not to a different product such as Ubuntu Core 20.

Comment: I was referring to version 20.04. I already updated it so there is no confusion. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do no remove these files manually. Use special applications instead - start with

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

and then use `purge-old-kernels` [script](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=purge-old-kernels) - install and run it with

```
sudo apt-get install byobu
sudo purge-old-kernels
```

Ideally you need only one latest 5.4.0-74 kernel, so for removal of 5.3.0-46 and 5.4.0-73 you can run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get purge --autoremove linux-headers-5.3.0-46 linux-image-5.3.0-46 linux-modules-5.3.0-46 linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-46

sudo apt-get purge --autoremove linux-headers-5.4.0-73 linux-image-5.4.0-73 linux-modules-5.4.0-73 linux-modules-extra-5.4.0-73
```

Comment: First and second scripts made no changes on `/boot`. The last one worked, releasing about 50MB. I'll try to upgrade again and see if it is enough.

Comment: It worked perfect, thanks!

Comment: Byobu seems like a great acquisition too. LOL